# driver not scraping the updated contents of tag and scraping the old contents

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the job description from the below image.
[image: Google jobs search]

What I am currently doing is to get all the job elements on the left and click each one of them and then scrape the job description. But the job description of the first job is being scraped all the time for all the job elements. Here is my code.

```
#Get the job elements.
def getElements(driver):
    xpath = '//div[@class="BjJfJf PUpOsf"]'
    return driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)

#scrape the job description for the specified element.
def setDescription(self, driver, element):
    #to click use .click(), action chains, or js code.
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element);
    time.sleep(6)
    xpath = '//div[@jsname="c6W1S"]//div[@class="YgLbBe YRi0le"]/div/span'
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute('textContent')
    self.description = text

#this is the for loop.
def getJobDetails(driver, jobs, job_elements):
jobDetails = []
for (job, element) in zip(jobs, job_elements):
    jobObject = JobPost(job)
    jobObject.setJobRole()
    jobObject.setCompany()
    jobObject.setSource()
    jobObject.setLocation()
    jobObject.setDescription(driver, element) #this is where I am calling the method.
    jobDetails.append(jobObject.getDetails())
return jobDetails

#this is how I am using the methods.
#loadFullJobsList(driver)
jobs = getAllJobs(driver)
#get all the job elements that is clickable.
job_elements = getElements(driver)
#get the list of job objects.
job_details = getJobDetails(driver, jobs, job_elements)
```

The setDescription method above was used in a loop where in each iteration an element was passed. I want to know why is the description of the currently clicked job not getting scraped and the description of the old job is being scraped. Answer to this would solve the issue. Thank you.

Here is the URL of the website : [website to be scraped](https://www.google.com/search?q=full%20stack%20developer%20jobs%20in%20india)

Comment: Please add url or sample html as well as an example of the loop.

Comment: @IODEV I have made the changes. Please look into it.

Comment: hi, the url seems incorrect.

Comment: @IODEV please check now. It should open full stack developer jobs and I think it is.

Comment: when you get list of all jobs then you should use `relative xpath` - wit dot at the beginnig - and search only inside selected element `job.find_...()` instead of `driver.find_...`. When you don't do this then it search in full HTML and it always find first element.

Comment: link to page doesn't work. Google shows message that `it doesn't support this browser, device or localization` - maybe this link works only in your country.

Comment: do you care about the scrolling as this generates more results?

Comment: @QHarr I have implemented the scrolling part. But that suggestion is out of context. My doubt is why the job description of the elements that was clicked not getting scraped and the description of the first job is getting scraped for all the elements.

Comment: @furas oh sorry man. I cant help with that. You could just search for full stack developer jobs on google search.

Comment: Why not simply extract the hrefs as you scroll and store in a list then .get to each one? I asked about the scrolling because I couldn't see it in your code and if I were writing a solution I wanted to know if you needed all results.

Comment: @QHarr there are no anchor tags here. What I tried was after clicking every element I stored the current url and then looped through each url to scrape the description. But still facting the same problem.

Comment: you can construct them by extracting the `[data-encoded-doc-id]` as `doc_id`  and inputting into `f'https://www.google.com/search?q=full stack developer jobs in india&ibp=htl;jobs#fpstate=tldetail&htidocid={doc_id}'`

Comment: Corrected url: https://www.google.com/search?q=full%20stack%20developer%20jobs%20in%20india . This only returns google search results. From what page did you get "job description" as shown in the picture?

Comment: @IODEV please click on 100+ more jobs located at the bottom of the table that you get after google search.

Comment: Does Not appear on my Mac using Chrome tho Safari shows a similar view. What browser and environment are you o

Comment: @IODEV I am using Chrome and Windows 10.

Comment: @QHarr thanks. I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: I've tested google from India using vpn and the result view seems to be location dependent. When connected to Europe and US will render different results.

Comment: The description ("gLoBe YRi0le") seems available within the same page thus there is no need for the extra `click()` in `setDescription`. Regarding the other problem it's possible you are passing the same element all the time. Have you checked that in the debugger?

Comment: @QHarr thanks buddy. Your solution was able to solve the problem. You are awesome!!

Comment: @IODEV thank you for the suggestions. I will try that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative as being to gather the "urls" for each listing then `.get` to them.

You can construct them by extracting all the `[data-encoded-doc-id]` as a list, then use, during a loop, as `doc_id` and inputting into `f'https://www.google.com/search?q=full stack developer jobs in india&ibp=htl;jobs#fpstate=tldetail&htidocid={doc_id}'`.